# How can I limit the size of the navigator in highstock.js?

Tags: javascript, navigation, highcharts

I have an application with long time series and I want to limit the maximum size of the navigator. I found the [afterSetExtremes](http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#xAxis.events.afterSetExtremes) event in the documentation, which I thought I could capture and then limit the size of the navigator from there. But it doesn't really work as expected. I seem to be able to limit the x size of the plotted data. But the navigator doesn't follow the size of the plotted data at all. Am i missing something here? How can I get it to work properly? Ideally the navigator would just remain fixed in size over a specific size. Is that possible to achieve?

Here the jsfiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/jn3cww8n/2/

```
$(function () {
$('#container').highcharts('StockChart', {
    xAxis: {
        events: {
            afterSetExtremes: function(e) {

                var dmin = Math.abs(e.min - this.oldMin),
                    dmax = Math.abs(e.max - this.oldMax),
                    range = e.max - e.min,
                    new_min = e.min,
                    new_max = e.max,
                    yr_range = range / 1000 / 60 / 60 / 24;
                if (0.0 === dmin && 0.0 < dmax) {
                    $('#report').html('Max changed ' + yr_range);

                    if (31536000000.0 < range) {
                        $('#report').html('setting new max');
                        new_max = new_min + 31536000000.0;
                    }

                } else if (0.0 < dmin && 0.0 === dmax) {
                    $('#report').html('Min changed ' + yr_range);

                    if (31536000000.0 < range) {
                        $('#report').html('setting new min');
                        new_min = new_max - 31536000000.0;
                    }

                } else {
                    $('#report').html('Nothing changed');
                }

                this.setExtremes(new_min, new_max);

            }
        }
    },
    rangeSelector: {
        selected: 1
    },
    series: [{
        name: 'USD to EUR',
        data: usdeur
    }]
});
});
```

Comment: The point of the navigator is that it gives you an overview of the entire series range you may have. If you want to limit what you can see/navigate to then maybe truncate your series to only include the range of values you want?

Comment: Users have to be able to navigate to which ever period they want to see, but I want to limit the period they can see of the greater time series. So I can't really truncate the time series. Data grouping doesn't work either because the time series don't make sense on a data grouped basis...

Comment: What do you mean by "limit the period they can see of the greater time series"? Do you mean (for example) if the data set is hourly you only want the user to see data for weekly time spans? Or do you mean if there is data for JAN to DEC you only want them to be able to view data from APR to AUG?

Comment: The former. Users should be able to access the whole time series, but with a limited size of the charted period.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I changed tack on this one. Instead of having a max size of the navigator, I restricted users from changing its size altogether.

I got the idea from [this](https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues/2017) post.

Just two changes required:

1. Blank the drawHandle function `Highcharts.Scroller.prototype.drawHandle = function () {};`
2. Commment out a few lines:

   ```
   22472,22476c22472,22476

   <                     //if (isOnNavigator && math.abs(chartX - zoomedMin - navigatorLeft) < handleSensitivity) {

   <                         //scroller.grabbedLeft = true;

   <                         //scroller.otherHandlePos = zoomedMax;

   <                         //scroller.fixedExtreme = baseXAxis.max;

   <                         //chart.fixedRange = null;

   ---

   >                     if (isOnNavigator && math.abs(chartX - zoomedMin - navigatorLeft) < handleSensitivity) {

   >                         scroller.grabbedLeft = true;

   >                         scroller.otherHandlePos = zoomedMax;

   >                         scroller.fixedExtreme = baseXAxis.max;

   >                         chart.fixedRange = null;

   22479,22483c22479,22483

   <                     //} else if (isOnNavigator && math.abs(chartX - zoomedMax - navigatorLeft) < handleSensitivity) {

   <                         //scroller.grabbedRight = true;

   <                         //scroller.otherHandlePos = zoomedMin;

   <                         //scroller.fixedExtreme = baseXAxis.min;

   <                         //chart.fixedRange = null;

   ---

   >                     } else if (isOnNavigator && math.abs(chartX - zoomedMax - navigatorLeft) < handleSensitivity) {

   >                         scroller.grabbedRight = true;

   >                         scroller.otherHandlePos = zoomedMin;

   >                         scroller.fixedExtreme = baseXAxis.min;

   >                         chart.fixedRange = null;

   22486,22487c22486

   <                     //} else if (chartX > navigatorLeft + zoomedMin - scrollbarPad && chartX < navigatorLeft + zoomedMax + scrollbarPad) {

   <                     if (chartX > navigatorLeft + zoomedMin - scrollbarPad && chartX < navigatorLeft + zoomedMax + scrollbarPad) {

   ---

   >                     } else if (chartX > navigatorLeft + zoomedMin - scrollbarPad && chartX < navigatorLeft + zoomedMax + scrollbarPad) {
   ```

Pretty clean all in all.